# How can SVG filled images be adapted to size?

Tags: svg

I need to fill in the rect image, the image is dynamic, size is not fixed, when I set properties, not fully populated found some pictures, only when the width and height of the image at the same time, can perfect show.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#9e9d9d">
    <defs>
        <pattern width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
                    id="picturePattern">
            <image width="1.0" height="1.0" xlink:href="img/timg_6_thumb.jpg"></image>
        </pattern>

        <pattern width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
                    id="picturePattern2">
            <image width="1.0" height="1.0" xlink:href="img/timg_6.jpg"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="150" y="100" width="500" height="300" style="stroke-width:2px;stroke:#ff1234;fill:url('#picturePattern')"></rect>

    <rect x="150" y="450" width="500" height="300" style="stroke-width:2px;stroke:#ff1234;fill:url('#picturePattern2')"></rect>
</svg>
```

As shown in the picture, the first picture is cropped, the width and height are 1080, and the second picture is 1920*1080.

[image]

How do I set the properties to automatically fit the image?

Comment: So what you want is to preserve the aspect ratio right? I'm not too clear if you want to have some *cover* or *contain*  feature, but anyway, How are set these dynamic images? Do you really have no way to know what their sizes, or at least their ratio will be? Because if it is for a browser, then by js you could retrieve these info and set your patterns `viewBox` accordingly to the image's size. Example [of cover](https://jsfiddle.net/cnx9zLqn/) and [of contain](https://jsfiddle.net/cnx9zLqn/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your demo. It seems that I can only do this.
If I could use a property like background-size, that would be nice.